# Command Prompt echo date returns nothing

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt, database-backups, sqlcmd

I have a batch/sql script pair used to back databases up. I recently went into the folder to get a db back and I saw that it wasn't working. I checked out my batch script and it's not giing me the day or month but the year is showing up as 'on'! My SQL script is working fine, and I want to add that my batch script used to work.

Here's my batch script

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS= " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET CDATE=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET mm=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=/ eol=/" %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET dd=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,3 DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET yyyy=%%B
SET date=%dd%-%mm%-%yyyy%

rem day month year check
echo %dd%
echo %mm%
echo %yyyy%

echo %date%

mkdir %date%

sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -i backupQuery.sql
```

and here's 'backupQuery.sql'

```
DECLARE @BackupLocation AS NVARCHAR(255) = 'C:\SQL\backups\'

/* Set @CurrentDate to a timestamp in mmddyyyy form */
DECLARE @CurrentDate AS NVARCHAR(255)

SET @CurrentDate = REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(CAST(DAY(GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR))) /*day number 1*/

+

CAST(DAY(GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR) /*day number 2*/

+ '-' +

REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR))) /*month number 1*/

+

CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR) /*month number 1*/

+ '-' +

CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR) /*year*/

DECLARE @DatabaseName AS NVARCHAR(255)

/* Get all databases except for the temporary database */
DECLARE Databases CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name
NOT IN
('tempdb',
'master',
'model',
'msdb')

OPEN Databases

FETCH NEXT FROM Databases
INTO @DatabaseName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Command AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @Command = 'BACKUP DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName) + ' TO DISK = ''' +
        @BackupLocation + @CurrentDate + '\' + @DatabaseName + '.BAK'''
    EXEC(@Command)
    FETCH NEXT FROM Databases
    INTO @DatabaseName
END

CLOSE Databases
DEALLOCATE Databases
```

They're meant to backup to a directory named after the current date, but it's coming through as --on?!

Comment: `%date%` is a built-in variable (in `cmd`), so it is a bad idea to overwrite it! open a new `cmd` window and type `%date%`, so you will see it returns the current date; so use a different variable name for your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Myself and [@aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl) managed to solve it, the reason it was breaking I believe was due to the fact that I was reassigning a system variable. All I had to do was use the DATE CONVERT format 6 in my SQL and the %date% variable in cmd. That solved it and I now have a format of dd-MMM-yy.